# How to display caller id (add identification entry) using CallKit on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit

I have created a basic Call Directory Extension in Xcode. The sample code that comes with it shows how to either block a phone number or display information about a phone number. Here is the bare minimum of code required to block phone number 22334455:

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        context.delegate = self

        context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: 22334455)
        //context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: 22334455, label: "Telemarketer")

        context.completeRequest()
    }
}

extension CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate {
    func requestFailed(for extensionContext: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext, withError error: Error) { }
}
```

According to the sample in Xcode, it should be just as easy to display caller id by using method addIdentificationEntry instead of addBlockingEntry, but I cannot get it to work.

Blocking works fine, but if I try to display caller id instead, the phone just displays the phone number. It does not show the text "Telemarketer" that I try to add.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was frustratingly simple.

**addIdentificationEntry() requires the country code, addBlockingEntry() does not.**

When I added 47 (Norway's country code) to the beginning of the phone number, it worked. Here is the working code to display caller id for Norwegian phone number 22334455 (+4722334455):

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

  override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    context.delegate = self

    context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: 4722334455, label: "Telemarketer")

    context.completeRequest()
  }
}
```

addBlockingEntry() works with both 22334455 and 4722334455 as input.

Comment: Is there a way to get the phone number that is currently calling instead of putting all known numbers and labels into the beginRequest call?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would like to know that myself. My plan is to have thousands of numbers, so I hope it is possible somehow to populate the CallDirectory on a schedule, and not when the phone is ringing.

Comment: Yeah me too - my plan would be to add about 50.000 numbers - Probably I could simply add a db query before I have to add 'em all

Comment: @Bjarte Aune Olsen: I have done demo app, but in Setting/Phone/Call Blocking & Identification/myapp is not enabling. Please help.

Comment: This means you're extension crashes for some reason. It's quite hard to find the cause of the error when the extension crashes, since you cannot debug it. What I have done is to create a log function in the extension that writes everything that happens to a log file. Then I have created a log reader function inside the app that can display the contents of the log file. To make this work, you first have to add both the app and the extension to the same App Group so they can read/write to the same log file.

Comment: Hei, @BjarteAuneOlsen! I'm currently working on a similar small app extension as you have been in this thread, and my problem is also debugging. Could you please share your log file function in the extension and also in the container app? Would be of great help seeing as my deadline is on Monday :-S

Comment: I might be able to put up some example code, but not before Monday, I'm afraid.